# Proof product propriety of bessel function

Tags: analysis, special-functions, bessel-functions, integral-transforms

The bessel function is given by:
$${J}_{n}(x) ={ \mathop{∑
}}_{k=0}^{∞} {{(−1)}^{k}\over
k!(n + k)!}{\left ({x\over
2}\right )}^{n+2k}.$$
and Translation operator can be wrighten as:
$$T_x f(y) = \frac{\Gamma(\nu+1)}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(\nu+\frac{1}{2}\right)} \int_{0}^\pi f\left(\sqrt{x^2+ y^2-2 xy\cos(\theta) }\right)(\sin(\theta))^{2v} \,d\theta.$$
i have trouble to prove :
$$T_x j_{n}(\lambda.)=j_{n}(\lambda x)j_{n}(\lambda y)$$ such that $x,y$ and $\lambda$ are  $\geq 0.$